# NSTimer and UIView Memory Mistake

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory

i create  views and release all objects. i used NSTimer  and

```
//at viewdidload
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 15.0
                                                      target: self
                                                    selector:@selector(selectorSwitcher:)
                                                    userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
    NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runner addTimer:timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

-(void)selectorSwitcher:(NSTimer *)timer {
        [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

but myviews can not delete from scrollview. Creating a more views up to others. How can i resolve this problem? 
Thanks

```
  if (tempView.frame.origin.x > createview.frame.size.width) {


            tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((lblname_marginleft + (i * widthOfView))-((i/sutun)*mview_width), lblname_margintop + ((i/sutun) * heightOfView), labelwidth, labelheight)];

            tempNumber = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((lblnumber_marginleft + (i* widthOfView))-((i/sutun)*mview_width), lblnumber_margintop + ((i/sutun) * heightOfView), labelwidth, labelheight)];

            tempyuzde= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((15 + (i*widthOfView))-((i/sutun)*mview_width), 10 + ((i/sutun) * heightOfView), labelwidth, labelheight)];

            tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((10 + (i* widthOfView)) - ((i/sutun)*mview_width), ((i/sutun) * heightOfView), widthOfView, heightOfView)];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be calling [`viewDidLoad`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - the system calls it once the view has loaded. To load the view, simply do:

```
UIView *view = self.view;
```

Calling `self.view` implicitly loads the XIB file. However the system also loads the view automatically when it is time to do so - what functionality are you trying to achieve?

---

Also, you should not be calling

```
NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Since by calling `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval...` you've already scheduled the timer - you don't need to schedule it again.